# Is there any method to accelerate the transferring single image time between client and server?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I wanna speed up the transferring time of single image between client and server. (i.e., different devices)

Left hand side was to sending an image (2.8MB png) from A to B then getting the results from B to A. It takes 300ms totally. Right hand side was to do on local only. It still need to take 30ms. (It was tested by internal network.)

[my experiments tested on local and remote.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6JFs.jpg)

The server was built by python flask framework. I am looking for a method which is able to get a really really fast way (or any frameworks) to transfer an image between 2 devices? In my case, I pay more attention on transferring time (efficiency)

### Here is my simple code

#### on client side

```
import requests
import time

start = time.time()
files  = {'file': open('test.png', 'rb')}

url = 'http://(server ip):5999/test'

myobj = {'data': 'key1'}
result  = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(result.json())
print("Total time: ", time.time()-start)
```

#### on server side

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test' ,methods=['POST'])
def predict():  
    start_pre = time.time()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
           return "someting went wrong"
           
    print('request files checking takes: ', time.time()-start_pre, flush=True)
    return jsonify({
        'result':'Get the results'
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5999, debug=True)
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Some thoughts... a) you are including the time to read the file from disk b) are you really using IP addresses or hostnammes - DNS lookups take time too c) you shouldn't be surprised it takes longer over a network and you should say what the network and devices are if you want a better answer.

Comment: Hi @Mark Setchell, thanks for your reply. (a) Yes, I included the reading file time, but obviously a majority of time was taking on transferring. (b) Using IP address is a common and simple way normally. Of course, if there is no more faster way to speed up, I'm glad to use any other better ways instead of using IP or hostnames if you have any idea or suggestions to share for me. (c) my devices were used the normal desktop. TBH, I am not really familiar with the knowledge of network domain (e.g., protocol) so I can try anything by any hints. Thanks again.